# In Elixir, why divide a token by 1?

Tags: elixir

In [Elixir's "Getting Started" guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#utf-8-and-unicode) I see the expressions: `byte_size/1` and `String.length/1`.

What is the significance of these expressions? What does the author want to communicate by dividing a token by 1?

Comment: You're asking about function/arity notation. 
You'll also see people divide numbers by 1 in elixir!
This would be very common to see:
   x = calculate_something
   x / 1
It converts a number to a float

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look into the [Basic types section](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html) you can see:

> Note: Functions in Elixir are identified by name and by number of arguments (i.e. arity). Therefore, is_boolean/1 identifies a function named is_boolean that takes 1 argument. is_boolean/2 identifies a different (nonexistent) function with the same name but different arity.

Comment: BTW: The "divided by arity" notation is taken directly from Erlang - the language which Elixir runs on top. In Erlang you can do things like' -export([fact/1])' which exports only the version of the function fact that has arity one and not two or more.